# Tieredmenu in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

Angular 2, v. 2.0.0 + PrimeNG. I would implement popup menu like this:

[image]

I install PrimeNG in my project with this command -> `npm install primeng --save`, and import `TieredMenuModule` in my app.module.ts -> `import {TieredMenuModule} from "primeng/primeng"`. Then i create component and import MenuItem -> `import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng'`, and all styles from node_modules (in my component of course):

```
import "../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"; 
import "../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"; 
import "../../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

Then i add `private items: MenuItem[]` and `ngOnInit()` function:

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = [ ... ]
 }
```

In my template i past this code:

```
<p-tieredMenu #menu [model]="items" [popup]="true"></p-tieredMenu>
<button #btn type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-list" label="Show" (click)="menu.toggle($event)"></button>
```

After all i get this:

[image]

The button are not blue and without label.

May be proble with style, or i dont import one more thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of importing all css in your component import all in the angular-cli.json file under the css object like this -

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css",
    "...."
],
```

Comment: @EduardArevshatyan your welcom :)

Comment: what about adding href to menu label ? or any external window.location.href - ""  to label ? Also any way to implement menu search in this ?

Comment: @RanveerSinghRajpurohit what are you trying to say? Didn't understand your point

Comment: i mean adding link to label to navigate to any page ?  other is if i have 1000 menu how i can search one out of those